What is the single word in Gabriela Mistral's La que camina?
The second stanza in Gabriela Mistral's poem La que camina introduces a "single word" that is somehow vital to the woman described in the poem. The poem's second and third stanzas can be translated as follows (emphasis mine):

The very wrinkle of the burning earth
leads it, scorches it and obeys it
and when she falls exhausted by the sun
it lifts her up again to go on with her.
Whether she lives it or dies
in the blind sand that loses everything,
of all that she has been given by fate
that single word is all she gathered
and she by it lives and by it dies.
That same word, the same, is the one she says
and is all she had and all she carries
and by its single syllable of fire
she can live as long as she wants.
Other words she would not learn
and the one she carries is her own sustenance
the more alone she goes the more she repeats it
but her ways are not understood.

How is that single word to be understood? Is it her sole guiding principle? (One that others don't understand?) Or is it possible to define it more accurately?
